# Under what conditions do I need to restart the Samba (smb) service?

Tags: linux, configuration, samba

This has been a long standing issue, and it would be nice to have an authoritative answer:

Under what conditions do I need to restart the Samba `smb` service?

I've had situations where I'd make a configuration change and Samba clients would pick them up without a service restart. I've had others where I add a stanza to the smb.conf file and *definitely* require a service restart to reflect the changes.

Is there a pattern or a set of guidelines to follow regarding this?

Comment: Is this Samba4 or an earlier version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to restart the smb service after every change that is made to the file to make sure that those changes take effect

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-startstop.html

That link also notes that the smb service will automatically reload after a few minutes after the file has been changed

Comment: `restart the smb service after every change` - That would really suck if you have a busy fileserver, and you need to add a new share ASAP.  Won't a restart kill any active transfers, and so on.

Comment: I didn't know the part about the daemon reloading automatically.

Comment: that's a good question @Zoredache I would think that most maintenance with your `smb.conf` file would be after hours or after the normal operations have ended but of course if something bad happened and you need to fix the smb file then that could be an issue

Comment: @ewwhite you could also use the command `systemctl reload smb` (from root) this will update the config without stopping and restarting the service so if what @Zoredache is saying about a busy file server and you need to add a share ASAP and not worry about losing any active transfers